# infimum in inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am just starting on analysis and I have a question about the concept of infimum:

Consider this scenario:

Theres is metric space (X,d) and a set $A \subseteq X$, hence for any $x,y \in X$ and $a\in A$

$ d(x,a) \leq d(x,y) +d(y,a) \; \forall a \in A$ .... this is true since d() is a valid metric.

Now can I justify the following statement:

$\inf_{a\in A} d(x,a) \leq d(x,y) + \inf_{a \in A} d(y,a)$

Basically $ d(x,A) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,A) $?

Is is it OK to take the infimum on both sides of the inequality? How to argue that doing so is right? the '$a\in A$' which minimises (weakly speaking here) d(x,a) need not be the same '$a\in A$' which minimises d(y,a)?

P.S: This question is in the backdrop of proving that the function d(x,A) is continuous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x,y$ be fixed members of the metric space and suppose $A$ is a subset of the metric space. Let $D = \{ d(x,a) \in \mathbb{R} : a \in A \}$ and let $E = \{ d(x,y) + d(y,a) \in \mathbb{R} : a \in A\}.$

Let arbitrary $e \in E$ be given. Then $e = d(x,y) + d(y,a)$ for some $a \in A$. Thus, there is some $d \in D$ (namely, $d(x,a)$) such that $d(x,a) \leq e.$ By definition of $\inf,$ $\inf D \leq d$ and therefore $\inf D \leq e.$ Since $e$ was arbitrary, this is true $\forall e \in E$. This shows that $\inf D$ is a lower bound for $E.$ Again, by definition of $\inf,$ this must mean that $\inf D \leq \inf E,$ as required. Yes, your assertion is ok.

Apologies for my earlier comment which was misleading because these two propositions are different:

- $\forall b \in B, \exists a \in A : a \leq b$
- $a \in A, b \in B \Rightarrow a \leq b$

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the reply, but I found the previous comment useful. If I have 2 sets A and B such that for every $a \in A$ there exists a $b \in B$ such that $a \leq b$ then, $infA \leq inf B$  because arguing otherwise  (i.e. infA >inf B)  leads to a conclusion that there must exist a $a \in A$ such that a < infA ! which by definition is not true.

Comment: @GautamPai: The proposition (as you state it) is *not* true. For example, consider $A=[0,1]$ and $B=\{-1,1\}.$ Clearly, for all $a\in A,$ there exists a $b\in B$ such that $a\le b.$ However, $\inf B<\inf A.$ On the other hand, the result mentioned by Shai isn't quite correct, either (consider $A$ empty and $B$ any non-empty set of reals). However, if $A,B\subseteq\Bbb R$ with $A\ne\emptyset$ such that for all $a\in A,b\in B$ we have $a\le b,$ then it does follow that $\inf A\le\inf B.$

Comment: Or, if $A,B\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that for all $b\in B$ there is some $a\in A$ such that $a\le b,$ then $\inf A\le\inf B.$

Comment: @CameronBuie: Oh yes thats true, $\forall b \in B $ there must exist an $a \in A$ such that $a \leq b$ not the other way around, otherwise picking up any $b \in B$ does not necessarily constrain me to any $a \in A$. In my original problem the exact case holds , since for any element in set $E = \{d(x,y) + d(y,a), a \in A\}$ there exists an element in set D =$\{d(x,a), a \in A\}$  (the same 'a' basically) such that the inequality holds (triangle), Thanks :)

Comment: @CameronBuie I confused myself a bit there. Never mind, thanks for your comment.

I'm happy to help, Gautam. If you agree with the response, could you mark it as 'accepted'? Otherwise it will join the list of unanswered questions on the site.